# How to pass a String with white spaces as a Parameter in JMeter inside a Groovy Code?

Tags: java, groovy, jmeter, assertion

I have a JMeter script where I want to send a string as an argument but the string has spaces in it. So, the String is actually being taken as two different parameters.

Preprocessor inside a Groovy sampler:

```
vars.put("Name","John Cena");
```

Groovy sampler log I am printing:

```
log.info("Arg 0 Value: "+args[0]);
log.info("Arg 1 Value: "+args[1]);
```

I want to parse the name in the first argument but right now because of a space in between, JMeter has taken it as a separate variable.

Image with logs:

[image]

Comment: Can you confirm the value that ${ExpectedStatusDetail} is taking please.

Comment: @0xadecimal, the value passed to ExpectedStatusDetail is "Trip Creation API returned status code 404" but while I print it, I only see Trip.

Comment: @AbhashRajbhandari, show the usage of ExpectedStatusDetail in script

Comment: @daggett I have edited the question with more description.

Comment: Look the answer below. And about args check how parameters passed in your operation system. Normally the params with spaces must be double-quoted. `"${Name}"` should work for this case.

Comment: @daggett, I tried to add double quotes but the result is the same. The log shows that "John is taken as the first parameter and the second parameter is taken as Cena".

Comment: @AbhashRajbhandari, seems args supports only space separated parameters. https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler : The contents of the Parameters field is put into the variable "Parameters". The string is also split into separate tokens using a single space as the separator, and the resulting list is stored in the String array `args`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use `Parameters` shorthand instead of `args` because

- `args` is a space-separated array of Strings
- and `Parameters` is the whole contents of the "Parameters" input

Demo:

[image]

Another approach is using [join()](https://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/groovy-jdk/java/lang/Object.html#join(java.lang.String)) function like:

```
log.info("Name: " + args.join(" "));
```

More information:

- [Groovy Goodness: Join Elements to a String](https://mrhaki.blogspot.com/2009/10/groovy-goodness-join-elements-to-string.html)
- [Apache Groovy - Why and How You Should Use It](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/groovy-new-black/)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to pass it as argument, in script use

```
 vars.get("Name")
```

To get variables, Or log:

```
 log.info("Name=" + vars.get("Name"));
```

Another option is to use [__urlencode function](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__urlencode) to replace space with `+` in Parameters:

```
${__urlencode(${Name})}
```